# SMTPServer with asyncore leave sockets open?

Tags: python, sockets, smtplib, asyncore

I have implemented a basic SMTPServer which works great but I'm encountering an issue and I don't know how I can fix it.

When checking the file descriptors opened for the $PID of the process running my script (`ls -l /proc/$PID/fd/ | grep "socket:" | wc -l`), the quantity of file descriptors keep increasing.

Since I'm filtering by "socket:", this clearly some sockets left open, certainly because some mail providers doesn't quit clearly.

I've tested locally some Python scripts connecting to that `SMTPServer` code, and even if I don't close the connection, when the client process stops, the client close the connection, and the file descriptor is removed.

I thought about implementing a timeout for waiting, or restarting the process every N connections, but these are just bad patches for a bigger problem.

Do you know where that would come from?

For information, my `process_message` wrapper is surounded by a

```
try:
    # ...
except:
    return '450 Please try again later"
```

So an exception coming from my code should be well handled.

Here's my code (simplified):

```
class MyMXServer(SMTPServer):
    def __init__(self, host='127.0.0.1', port=25):
        self.srs = SRS.new(os.getenv('SRS_KEY', 'some passwd'))
        return SMTPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), None)

    def process_message(self, greeting, peer, mailfrom, recipients, data, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self._process_message(greeting, peer, mailfrom, recipients, data, **kwargs)
        except:
            logging.getLogger('err').exception('[EXCEPTION]')
            return '450 Please try again later.'

    def _process_message(self, greeting, peer, mailfrom, recipients, data, **kwargs):
        # Various things like checking DNSBL, SPF, Spam, etc
```

Comment: Do you have control over the clients or are you accepting connections from all over the big bad Internet? Some clients could leave the connection hanging just because they are sloppy, or worse.

Comment: In other news, there will be a workshop about using `grep -c` instead of `grep | wc -l` after the regular schedule finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without seeing your code. However, you've already implemented the initial components of exception handling. `else` may not be necessary, but it sounds like a `finally` clause is a requirement in this situation. Finish the block to ensure the socket is closed:

```
try:
    # unreliable process
except:
    return '450 Please try again later"
else:
    # successful outcome
finallY:
    socket.close()
```

Comment: Will finally be called only if the except has been called? Or regardless of the outcome of the previous items?

Comment: It's well documented in the reference. It will be called regardless.

Comment: `finally` will always be called whether the `try` succeeds or fails.

Comment: This won't work (just checked with the code) as the method may returns '250' if everything is fine, and will wait for the next command. Closign the socket will causes issues.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions <- there

Comment: If my hypothesis of having some clients not closing the connection properly is right, the issue could happen before my code is run (like right after the "HELO" command). That's why I haven't pasted my code.

Comment: Async complicates matters, you have to figure out where the asyncore server keeps the connection open but that's pretty much impossible without seeing more of your code. Maybe you need to wrap your code in an object which has an explicit destructor which takes care of cleanup.

Comment: @CyrilN. - That is the purpose of the `else` clause. If the `try` succeeds, go to `else`. After `else` completes, go to `finally`. If `try` does not succeed, go to `except`, then go to `finally`. This is the exact process you need to properly ensure the socket is closed. You cannot rely on the client performing in a certain manner.

Comment: I've added part of my code that handle the response but again, I don't see what could fail there. As for the idea of wrapping it up in a class to handle the destruction, if my hypothesis is correct, it won't work (as the process hangs)

Comment: I finally thinks what is the culprit (tldr: me). I was so focused on the "socket" issue that I was certain it was related to Smtpd. But I forgot I was using another socket instance elsewhere in the code and guess what? That socket was sometimes throwing exceptions resulting in the socket not being closed... I fixed it. I don't have the certainty it's this, but all points towards it! I'll see if the FD still keeps increasing. Thanks for your help !